# Unknown column 'submittedby' in 'field list'

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, email

I am pretty new to PHP and MySQL and I just can't figure this one out. I 
have searched all around the forum but haven't found an answer I can make sense of.

I get the following error: Unknown column 'submittedby' in 'field list', the problem is with this line of the code -

```
$update="update users set enrol_Date='".$enrol_Date."', username='".$username."', firstname='".$firstname."', lastname='".$lastname."', identificationCard='".$identificationCard."', email='".$email."',contact='".$contact."', submittedby='".$submittedby."' where id='".$id."'";
```

The whole code is:

```
<?php
  require('db.php');
  include("auth.php");
  $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
  $query = "SELECT * from users where id='".$id."'"; 
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ( mysqli_error());
  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
?>

<?php
  $status = "";
  if(isset($_POST['new']) && $_POST['new']==1)
  {
    $id=$_REQUEST['id'];
    $enrol_Date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $username =$_REQUEST['username'];
    $firstname =$_REQUEST['firstname'];
    $lastname =$_REQUEST['lastname'];
    $identificationCard =$_REQUEST['identificationCard'];
    $email =$_REQUEST['email'];
    $contact =$_REQUEST['contact'];
    $submittedby = $_SESSION["username"];
    $update="update users set enrol_Date='".$enrol_Date."', username='".$username."', firstname='".$firstname."', lastname='".$lastname."', identificationCard='".$identificationCard."', email='".$email."',contact='".$contact."', submittedby='".$submittedby."' where id='".$id."'"; 
    mysqli_query($con, $update) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $status = "Profile Updated Successfully. </br></br>
    <a href='view.php'>View Updated Record</a>";
    echo '<p style="color:#FF0000;">'.$status.'</p>';
  }else {
?>
```

Here is my form code:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action=""> 
  <input type="hidden" name="new" value="1" />
  <input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" />
  <label for="username"> Username : </label>
  <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
  required value="<?php echo $row['username'];?>" /></p>
  <label for="firstname"> Firstname : </label>
  <p><input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" 
  required value="<?php echo $row['firstname'];?>" /></p>
  <label for="lastname"> Lastname : </label>
  <p><input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" 
  required value="<?php echo $row['lastname'];?>" /></p>
  <label for="i/cno"> I/C No : </label>
  <p><input type="text" name="identificationCard" placeholder="I/C" 
  required value="<?php echo $row['identificationCard'];?>" /></p>
  <label for="email"> Email : </label>
  <p><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" 
  required value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" /></p>
  <label for="contact"> Contact : </label>
  <p><input type="text" name="contact" placeholder="Contact" 
  required value="<?php echo $row['contact'];?>" /></p>
  <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if `submittedby` really existed in your table?

Comment: show your database schema

Comment: share your table `users` structure

Answer (score 0):

It means your "users" table does not contain "submittedby" column. You will need to add this column to your table for this script to work.

Answer (score 0):

Plainly, submittedby is not a column in the table.

FWIW, I find this much easier to read...

```
update="
update users 
   set enrol_Date = '$enrol_Date'
     , username = '$username'
     , firstname = '$firstname'
     , lastname = '$lastname'
     , identificationCard = '$identificationCard'
     , email '$email'
     , contact = '$contact'
     , submittedby = '$submittedby' 
 where id = '$id'
";
```

... however, you should really be using parametrised queries with mysqli, so see about that too.

Answer (score -1):

check `"submittedby"` field exist in your users table or not